# how to convert low resolution image into high resolution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have this image which has a resolution of 240*320 which I have used to analyze in MATLAB. So now I have to convert this into a high resolution image.What would be the MATLAB code to convert a low resolution image into a high resolution image?

Comment: What have your tried so far? Not to damper your efforts but it's nearly impossible to improve resolution once an image has been captured. There are a few model-based approaches that I am aware of, but those are not robust and certainly work off of big assumptions about the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use **imresize** to increase the image size.

> B = imresize(A, scale)

Example to increase an image by a factor of 2:

```
A = imread('example.png');
B = imresize(A, 2);
```

Further reading:

> http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html

Note: This will only increase the number of pixels and not increase the detail the image contains. Depending on the image many **image processing** techniques exist that increase certain detail with varying degrees of success.

Comment: +1 on your caveat regarding quality.  A lot of people forget that adding more pixels to the image doesn't necessarily mean better quality.  Also, you can use `imresize` to manually specify what output size image you want.  It doesn't have to be restricted to specifying a scale factor.